# How would one set or override a Fallback font for characters in second language?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style, fonts

In my website, posts occasionally contain characters from a second language (Urdu), which the google web-font set by my theme, of course does not recognize and resorts to a fallback font. I was wondering if there might be a way to override the fallback font for unrecognized characters to one of my liking(that supports Arabic/Urdu script) such as the google early access Noto fonts which include arabic and urdu fonts. Would this work as I understand it should? will any characters in Arabic/Urdu script be rendered with the specified font by doing so? I would love to know how one could implement/ enqueue necessary files in a WordPress theme. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanking you very much for your time,
Sameer

**excerpt from post with arabic characters:**

> ALL MEMBERS, السلام عليكم With the arrival of summer, the Swimming
>   Pool & Gymnasium activities shall commence from Saturday the 1st of
>   APRIL 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only solution is `unicode-range` in your `@font-face` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range). Unfortunately you've to note every single character (or a range) you would like to display via the font in your basic `@font-face`.

After that you can enqueue another webfont with the missing chars and make it available:

```
font-family: 'font without arabic chars', 'font with arabic chars', sans-serif
```

Of course there are a few browser issues in older browsers:
http://caniuse.com/#search=unicode-range

Comment: @SameerAli any news on your issue?

Comment: my sincere apologies for the late response, regrettably time and commitments would not permit to follow up till now, I was hoping to follow your example thoroughly and post back, I am new to web development and things are taking longer than i hoped, I am attempting your solution and will post back asap on the results. many thanks for your help, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: I was wondering what is the reason for the @ font-face rule and unicode range, I followed your instructions by enqueueing the arabic font in the themes functions.php, and simply addding the css `.entry-content{font-family:Noto Sans, cairo !important;}` (cairo is the arabic font) This seems to be working without specifying unicode characters. wherever there are arabic/urdu characters are being rendered with the cairo font. I was wondering what are the advantages of using the @ font-face rule.

Comment: you’re totally right. of course you can do it without `unicode-range`. you can use `unicode-range` in case you want exclude parts or single chars of each font which you load via `@font-face`. Especially in your case – when you want to exclude the arabic range from _Noto Sans_ and fallback to _cairo_ you can do it with `unicode-range`.

_Noto_ should include a comprehensive range of languages as you can see in their project website: https://www.google.com/get/noto/

you need to make your webfonts available in your stylesheet via @font-face like in this example https://jsfiddle.net/h906qu6v/

Comment: so by setting a unicode range only the characters I specify will use the fallback font? so does this mean that the entire font is not downloaded to the client machine and only the characters specified ? does enqueueing a font download the entire font regardless whether it is used or not? I guess my question is does this technique save bandwidth/page load time in any way?

Comment: it will load the entire font file – so you wouldn't save load time. but in case, e.g. your have a page with all-latin characters the arabic font will not be loaded. but: on fonts.google.com you can in- and exclude subsets (e.g. keep arabic, remove other languages) in _CUSTOMIZE_ in your "shopping cart" – this will definitely save load time.

Comment: ah, i see, I noticed in the "shopping cart" for the particular Cairo font in question, i was unable to deselect the Latin subset, i suppose I could work around this by generating my own font which does not include the latin characters, thank you s-t, im very much obliged for your time and all your help. cheers!